# Menu Screen Display Jumbled (Minecraft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

On the menu screen, the GUI and the display overall are distorted. It looks very chaotic and "jumbled?". It also appears to be not fully rendered. Before the menu screen, only "MOJ" is visible instead of "MOJANG." I've looked everywhere, but no one seems to be encountering the same problem. I'm not entirely sure what is causing this to happen, alongside its solution. So can anyone help identify and guide me to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to arqade! Do other games work? What steps have you taken so far to solve your issue?

Comment: So far, I've tried to override high dpi scaling behavior, play in full-screen mode, and enabling v-sync. And yes, other games and applications work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like GPU or screen resolution problem

See this: [How to fix Minecraft Screen Glitching](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/minecraft-windows-10-edition-title-screen-glitch/6fa95598-a314-4761-ab9e-ef9484d085be?auth=1)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'll update you once I've tried them out

Comment: UPDATE: I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the game and it still won't work. I've also tried to system restore.

Comment: Have you tried Installing and reinstalling graphic drivers?

Comment: Installing and reinstalling? I don't quite understand. Do you mean I should uninstall the driver and then reinstall it, or?

Comment: This is the in-game display: https://imgur.com/f6WaEu4

Comment: @COSMO Guide to reinstalling or updating drivers: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/update-drivers-in-windows-10-ec62f46c-ff14-c91d-eead-d7126dc1f7b6

Comment: This is definitely related to your graphic drivers. Press ctrl + shift + esc to see if task manager flickers. If it does then your gpu is corrupt. also do check for latest updates on you drivers

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! I appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome! @COSMO